# JavaScript Framerate Measurement

Tags: javascript, android, html, animation, frame-rate

I've been struggling fruitlessly to implement a way to measure how many frames per second are rendered accurately in my app (It is an Android app using HTML5/JavaScript and built using Cordova).

The application uses a number of animation techniques; CSS keyframe animations and transitions/transforms present in the app's stylesheets, and some implemented in JavaScript using `jQuery.animate()`. One of the methods I've seen here on Stack Overflow is to use `requestAnimFrame` to do so.

I've tried out Gerben's method [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279729/calculate-fps-in-canvas-using-requestanimationframe), but that returns values that don't appear accurate (The FPS seems to cycle between the same three arbitrary values whenever I test the app, and whichever page of the app I'm on, regardless of whether or not it is animation-intense).

Does anyone have any advice to get me on the right track?