# Is it possible to estimate average FPS for requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a tweened framebased animation and to calculate duration i need a FPS value for requestAnimationFrame. Now I use 60 which works fine on desktop devices but on my Android FPS is dropped down to cá 30 even if I pass empty function to requestAnimationFrame. I am not asking for timebased animation or using timeout for loop but if there is some way to make a close quess for average FPS requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279729/calculate-fps-in-canvas-using-requestanimationframe

Comment: I suppose I could run an empty loop on page load  and calculate avarage FPS-value ?